# Jekyll escapes output from CoffeeScript converter (with Octopress)

Tags: coffeescript, jekyll

I'm running a [Octopress](http://octopress.org/) blog which is based on [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll). Now I wanted to add some Javascript which I like to write in CoffeeScript.

I followed this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/959938) to create a simple converter that compiles CoffeeScript to Javascript:

```
module Jekyll
  require 'coffee-script'

  class CoffeeScriptConverter < Converter
    safe true
    priority :low

    def matches(ext)
      ext =~ /coffee/i
    end

    def output_ext(ext)
      '.js'
    end

    def convert(content)
      begin
        CoffeeScript.compile content
      rescue StandardError => e
        puts "CoffeeScript error: #{e.message}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that the generated Javascript file has all quotes escaped (single quotes by `&#8216;` and double quotes by `&#8220;`)

When I output the generated Javascript code in the `convert` method, it looks fine (quotes are not escaped).
I googled a lot but nobody seems to have this problem.
What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Octopress runs the content through [RubyPants](https://github.com/jmcnevin/rubypants) by default (see `plugins/octopress_filters.rb`). Disabling RubyPants did the trick!

Comment: How did you do this? Did this affect other content? Can you edit the code above with this fix for others to use?

Comment: Just comment out this line: https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/8753a6b00cad6c4c822df79967c6d5a8fb41b4dd/plugins/octopress_filters.rb#L19

Answer (score 0):

Since RubyPants ignores content inside HTML comments we can disable RubyPants filtering on the fly by surrounding the output in HTML comments. This also eliminates the need to modify the OctoPress original code.

I've done just that in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2925325).